# Получения IP адреса и порта по имени хоста

Tags: c++, qt, ip, port

Как узнать IP адрес и порт, имея хост?

Например, есть хост `vk.com`, хочу получить его IP и порт. Как правильно это сделать?

Пробовал сделать это, но получаю `x = -1`

```
QUrl url("vk.com");
url.setScheme("http");
int x = url.port();
```

Comment: `QUrl` - это просто представление url, от того что вы его создали он не будет коннектиться куда-то там и порт определять. А то что вам нужно называется сканирование портов - nmap такое умеет. Вручную - вы должны перебрать сами все порты, и к каждому порту пытаться подключиться, те к которому удалось подключиться - работают, только ещё надо определять по какому протоколу они работают и всё такое.

Comment: Ну а чтобы получить ip по доменному имени воспользуйтесь [QHostInfo](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qhostinfo.html#details)

Comment: да скорее всего если схема http, то порт 80 (если не указано другое). И не нужно никаких сканирований. Правда я не уверен, работает ли оно на 80 порту, скорее всего давно полностью переехало на https/443 (а проверить я это никак не могу  - оно давно не работает)

Comment: Ну да, для различных протоколов можно пытаться использовать порты по-умолчанию, тогда вам остаётся только ip (если точнее - список ip) для требуемого доменного имени получить.

Comment: @vt-egorov для чего перебираются порты? И на каком уровне это происходит?